# appending info to a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web site with which I am adding records to a database and The info I am also writing to a log file which is part of the website.
The info is written to the file fine...the only question I do have is how to add information with each input into the database.
As it is at the moment the information is put int the lof file but with each new insert into the database the existing record in the log file seems to be overwritten and replaced with a new insert so that there is always only one record added to the log file.
Advice perhaps...
this is the code I used in the btnClick event.

```
protected void btnSubmitRating_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rating = 0;
    try
    {
        if (radRating.Items[0].Selected)
        {
            rating = 1;
        }
        if (radRating.Items[1].Selected)
        {
            rating = 2;
        }
        else if (radRating.Items[2].Selected)
        {
            rating = 3;
        }
        else if (radRating.Items[3].Selected)
        {
            rating = 4;
        }
        else if (radRating.Items[4].Selected)
        {
            rating = 5;
        }
        FileStream rate = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/rateBooks.log"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(rate);
        rate.Close();


        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/rateBooks.log"));
        sw.WriteLine("userName " + txtUserName.Text + " " + "bookTitle " + txtBookTitle.Text + " " + "ISBN " + txtISBN.Text);
        sw.Close();


        Service s = new Service();
        s.bookRatedAdd(txtBookTitle.Text, rating, txtReview.Text, txtISBN.Text, txtUserName.Text);
        btnSubmitRating.Enabled = false;
        radRating.Enabled = false;            
    }
    catch (Exception em)
    {
        lblError.Text = em.Message; 
        //lblError.Text = "This book has already been reviewed by yourself?";
    }
}
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this whole block of code:

```
FileStream rate = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/rateBooks.log"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(rate);
rate.Close();

StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/rateBooks.log"));
sw.WriteLine("userName " + txtUserName.Text + " " + "bookTitle " + txtBookTitle.Text + " " + "ISBN " + txtISBN.Text);
sw.Close();
```

To this single line:

```
File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~/rateBooks.log"), "userName " + txtUserName.Text + " " + "bookTitle " + txtBookTitle.Text + " " + "ISBN " + txtISBN.Text + Environment.NewLine);
```

Note that I'm now adding manually `NewLine` to each line.

Answer (score 2):

Read this: [How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)

In that, example #4 shows how to append to a file:

```
// Example #4: Append new text to an existing file
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt", true))
{
  file.WriteLine("Fourth line");
}
```

So you could do this with your code and it should work:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/rateBooks.log"), true);
sw.WriteLine("userName " + txtUserName.Text + " " + "bookTitle " + txtBookTitle.Text + " " + "ISBN " + txtISBN.Text);
sw.Close();
```

**EDIT:** Just use Shadow Wizard's answer, it is much cleaner...

Comment: No need to create any streams, `File` class holds static helpers for that. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - yeah, I agree. It is not how I'd do it, but I figure it is good to pass on the info and show how he could make a minor edit to his existing code. It is better to show best practice though for sure...

Comment: Yep I also tend to offer small fix to existing code many times so it's all good. :-)